# ipmitool gives "Authentication type NONE not supported"

Tags: ipmitool

I'm executing below command from ubuntu 12.04 and get error

ipmitool -H 192.168.0.254 -U root -P root user list
Authentication type NONE not supported
Authentication type NONE not supported
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
    Get User Access command failed (channel 14, user 1)

I have enabled verbose option and have following output

```
ipmitool -H 192.168.0.254 -U root -P root user list -vvv
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[0], open=[134852928]
IPMI LAN host 192.168.0.254 port 623
Sending IPMI/RMCP presence ping packet
send_packet (12 bytes)
06 00 ff 06 00 00 11 be 80 00 00 00
recv_packet (27 bytes)
06 00 ff 06 00 00 11 be 40 00 10 00 00 11 be 00
00 00 00 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Received IPMI/RMCP response packet: 
IPMI NOT Supported
ASF Version unknown
RMCP Version 1.0
RMCP Sequence 255
IANA Enterprise 1162752

ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1], open=[134852928]
>> IPMI Request Session Header
>>   Authtype   : NONE
>>   Sequence   : 0x00000000
>>   Session ID : 0x00000000
>> IPMI Request Message Header
>>   Rs Addr    : 20
>>   NetFn      : 06
>>   Rs LUN     : 0
>>   Rq Addr    : 81
>>   Rq Seq     : 00
>>   Rq Lun     : 0
>>   Command    : 38
send_packet (23 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 20 18
c8 81 00 38 0e 04 35
recv_packet (30 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 81 1c
63 20 00 38 00 01 80 18 02 a2 02 00 00 69
ipmi message header (30 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 81 1c
 63 20 00 38 00 01 80 18 02 a2 02 00 00 69
<< IPMI Response Session Header
<<   Authtype   : NONE
<<   Sequence   : 0x00000000
<<   Session ID : 0x00000000
<< IPMI Response Message Header
<<   Rq Addr    : 81
<<   NetFn      : 07
<<   Rq LUN     : 0
<<   Rs Addr    : 20
<<   Rq Seq     : 00
<<   Rs Lun     : 0
<<   Command    : 38
<<   Compl Code : 0x00
get_auth_capabilities (8 bytes)
 01 80 18 02 a2 02 00 00
Channel 01 Authentication Capabilities:
  Privilege Level : ADMINISTRATOR
  Auth Types      : 
  Per-msg auth    : disabled
  User level auth : disabled
  Non-null users  : disabled
  Null users      : disabled
  Anonymous login : disabled

Authentication type NONE not supported
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1], open=[134852928]
>> IPMI Request Session Header
>>   Authtype   : NONE
>>   Sequence   : 0x00000000
>>   Session ID : 0x00000000
>> IPMI Request Message Header
>>   Rs Addr    : 20
>>   NetFn      : 06
>>   Rs LUN     : 0
>>   Rq Addr    : 81
>>   Rq Seq     : 01
>>   Rq Lun     : 0
>>   Command    : 38
send_packet (23 bytes)
 06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 20 18
 c8 81 04 38 0e 04 31
recv_packet (30 bytes)
 06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 81 1c
 63 20 04 38 00 01 80 18 02 a2 02 00 00 65
ipmi message header (30 bytes)
 06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 81 1c
 63 20 04 38 00 01 80 18 02 a2 02 00 00 65
<< IPMI Response Session Header
<<   Authtype   : NONE
<<   Sequence   : 0x00000000
<<   Session ID : 0x00000000
<< IPMI Response Message Header
<<   Rq Addr    : 81
<<   NetFn      : 07
<<   Rq LUN     : 0
<<   Rs Addr    : 20
<<   Rq Seq     : 01
<<   Rs Lun     : 0
<<   Command    : 38
<<   Compl Code : 0x00
get_auth_capabilities (8 bytes)
 01 80 18 02 a2 02 00 00
Channel 01 Authentication Capabilities:
  Privilege Level : ADMINISTRATOR
  Auth Types      : 
  Per-msg auth    : disabled
  User level auth : disabled
  Non-null users  : disabled
  Null users      : disabled
  Anonymous login : disabled

Authentication type NONE not supported
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
Failed to open LAN interface
Get User Access command failed (channel 14, user 1)
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Please use -I lanplus, such as:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.0.254 -U root -P root user list
```

Comment: Thanks for providing information. This helps a lot and solved issue. Once again thanks..

Comment: ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.0.254 -U root -P root user list

Comment: Thanks.  Works on Solaris 10 interrogating Oracle X5 iLOM: `ipmitool -I lanplus -H 10.10.10.10 -U XXXXX -P XXXX -v sdr list`

Comment: And in my case adding `-I lanplus`  doesn't help, it gives me `error in open session response message : invalid role

Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session`

Comment: @aircraft, yes. Added as an answer. Thanks for poking me)

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem by telling IPMI which auth methods IPMI should use explicitly:

```
ipmitool lan set 1 auth $username MD5,PASSWORD
```

This command could be executed only locally if you can't connect from remote location